# How to send and download a file as a response to GraphQL query in java

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I want to send an .xlsx file as a response of graphql query. And as part of mutation, I want to upload .xlsx file

can anybody give me an idea how can I implement it in java on server side? I searched online, but couldn't find a proper solution